# Compare two strings and match them regardless of order

Tags: ruby

Given the following array:

```
@array = ["012", "345", "678", "048", "246", "036", "147", "258"]
```

How could I check if the 3 digits in the variable, `@register`, matches any of the 3 digits in the array without caring about the order of said 3 digits?

I.e. for [sic] `@register` with the values `"012"`, `"210"`, `"102"`, `"246"` and `"174"` will yield `true`, but `"014"` and `"247"` will not.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "regardless of string order".

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "values in a variable". A variable can hold only one value.

Comment: Thanks, i have edited the question to better explain the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'set'

def is_present?(array, register)
  array.map { |s| s.chars.to_set }.include?(register.chars.to_set)
end

array = ["012", "345", "678", "048", "246", "036", "147", "258"]
["012", "210", "102", "246", "174", "014", "247"].each { |s|
  puts "#{s} => #{is_present?(array, s)}" }
012 => true
210 => true
102 => true
246 => true
174 => true
014 => false
247 => false
```

If (unlike the OP's example) leading zeroes may be omitted in the value of `register` or the elements of `array` (e.g., `s = "12"` rather than `s = "012"`), it would be prudent to pad the string with zeroes to make them all three characters in length:

```
array.map { |s| s.rjust(3, "0").chars.to_set }.
      include?(register.rjust(3, "0").chars.to_set)
```

Comment: Kudos on your approach to testing. DRY seems to have escaped me on this occasion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just noticed the ruby version I am operating on is 2.2.0 but set requires the newer 2.4.

Comment: Carrein, [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) has been a part of Ruby since v1.8.7 and probably before that. Nor do I see any other methods that I used that are not old standbys,

Answer (score 1):

Probably much less efficient than the other answers, but well it seems quite semantic to use `Array#permutation` here, so:

```
def any_perm? str, arr
  arr.any? { |e| e.chars.permutation(3).include? str.chars }
end

array = ["012", "345", "678", "048", "246", "036", "147", "258"]

any_perm? "210", array #=> true
any_perm? "102", array #=> true
any_perm? "012", array #=> true
any_perm? "852", array #=> true

any_perm? "111", array #=> false
any_perm? "259", array #=> false
```

Obviously the `3` in the method can be generalised if you like.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given two arrays of values, like:

```
a = %w[ 012 345 678 ]
b = %w[ 345 678 123 ]
c = %w[ 000 111 123 ]
```

Then you can compute intersections using the `Array#&` method:

```
a & b
# => ["345", "678"] 
a & c
# => []
b & c
# => ["123"]
```

You can also quickly test for any overlap:

```
(a & b).any?
# => true
(a & c).any?
# => false
(b & c).any?
# => true
```